# Replace sub string's characters with their complement character

Tags: java

I am asking an input from the user say "ATGC", reversing it, and then want to replace each character with its complement In my case, A and G are complement of each other, similarly T and C are also the complements of each other. What I expected, if input is AATGGCCC, then my code first reverse it and generate CCCGGTAA, and then I need a logic of complement which should give me the final out put like this TTTAACGG

I tried my first step, even I also tried the function which calculate complement. What I did, I just passed the reverse string to function, which undergoes into the if...else condition and find each letter by using contains() method,If 'A' will be then replace it with 'G', but it is not optimal, because  there is also condition to find 'G', if G is there then it will replace it by 'A', so i am kind of stuck by developing the logic.

```
class DNAString {

    private static String returnFinalComplement(String list) {
        String replace = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {

        if (list.contains("A")) {
            list = list.replaceAll("A", "G");
        } else if (list.contains("G")) {
            list = list.replaceAll("G", "A");
        } else if (list.contains("T")) {
            list = list.replaceAll("T", "C");
        } else if (list.contains("C")) {
            list = list.replaceAll("C", "T");
        }

    }
    return list;
}

public static String reverseIt(String source) {
    int i, len = source.length();
    StringBuilder dest = new StringBuilder(len);

    for (i = (len - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        dest.append(source.charAt(i));
    }

    return dest.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the input");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    String reverseString = reverseIt(s);
    String revereStringComplement = returnFinalComplement(reverseString);
    System.out.println("reverse string " + revereStringComplement);

}
}

Enter the input
ATGC
reverse string CATA
```

Expected output : GCAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to stick with `replaceAll` then you'll need to go through an intermediate letter.

```
list = list
   .replaceAll("A", "X") // Assuming someone hasn't invented an X base.
   .replaceAll("G", "A")
   .replaceAll("X", "G")
   .replaceAll("C", "X")
   .replaceAll("T", "C")
   .replaceAll("X", "T")
   ;

/* **Edit:** I think I've got that the right way around now. */
```

This is similar to the situation if you wanted to swap to variables. Say `a` and `b`.

```
int aOrig = a;
a = b;
b = aOrig;
```

It's probably better to explode the `String`.

```
StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : list.toCharArray()) {
    buff.append(
        c=='G' ? 'A' :
        c=='A' ? 'G' :
        c=='T' ? 'C' :
        c=='C' ? 'T' :
        c // perhaps throw
    )
)
return buff.toString();
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tom, I am not stick with only replace, even I would like to welcoming if there is another good approach for doing the same.

Comment: how for each can applicable for expression like toString()?

Comment: @user10753505 That should have been `toCharArray`. I've already spotted and fixed that.

Comment: It worked like a charm Tom, thank you so much, in addition I also want you people to suggest me the best practices for the same code above, so it will be beneficial for me and others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your `returnFinalComplement` is wrong in a few places. Firstly you loop over the string but each time the operation you perform inside the loop affects the entire string, not just the char you are currently looking at. Secondly you "first" replace every `A` with a `G` and then replace every `G` with an `A`, that means that everything that was previously an `A` OR a `G` is now an `A`.

You could either change the logic of `returnFinalComplement` or drop it completely and instead use your `reverseIt` function to not append `source.charAt(i)` but its complement.